# Why does a 2nd monotouch viewcontrollers toolbar buttons eventhandler not get called

Tags: c#, uiviewcontroller, event-handling, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a monotouch project with a RootViewController that initiallay loads up the viewcontrollers :-

```
this.AddChildViewController( secondViewController );
this.AddChildViewController( firstViewController );
View.AddSubview( firstViewController.View  );
firstViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController( this );
```

each viewController contains a toolbar whose buttons are added like:

```
loaderButton  = new MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonItem( UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, loaderClickHandler );
```

or

```
closeButton   = new MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonItem( "Close", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, new EventHandler( closeClickHandler ) );
```

where loaderClickHandler is just:

```
private void loaderClickHandler( System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e )
{
  System.Console.WriteLine( "loaderClickHandler()" );
}
```

This all works fine, (but please, let me know if there is a better way)
The problem comes with the secondViewController (which is basically the same as the first, just different text).

when it is switched to by the RootViewController with:

```
this.Transition( firstViewController, secondViewController, 0.2, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, () => {  }, (bool finished) => { secondViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController( this ); } );
```

It displays fine but it's toolbar buttons don't call the event handler methods when clicked/touched ?
All variables(loaderButton) are class level.

Anybody know why ? or what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH !

It helps when you add the toolbar AFTER any other items !